# How to setup IntelliJ 13 to compile junit tests in Play Framework project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, playframework-2.0

I created new Play framework 2.3.4 project with IntelliJ IDEA 13, everything works fine except for unit tests. When I create a test and run it intelliJ says:

```
Class not found: "myclass"
```

When I run *activator test* it compiles the class and I can then run it from intelliJ, but I would like to solve this issue because running activator after every change in test is very uncomfortable.

Neither turning of external build server or updating play and intelliJ to latest version didn't help.

Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: Ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-7590

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Run/Debug Configurations" of your unit test and change "Use classpath of module" to "root" module and set "Make Project" in Before launch section. At least it helped me to solve the same error.